# How can we parse a aspx page content to an Android app?

Tags: java, android, asp.net, http, jsoup

I want to login to a web application from an Android App.
How can i parse ASPX control to my Android app?
Actually i want to make an android app for my university website.i want user to signin to their university account and see timetable.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the HTML from accessing the page. From a client perspective, a page with .aspx is just a traditional web page.

However, you'll find that's an exceedingly bad way to go about things. If the design of the website changes, it will break your app.

If you really want to build an app, get permission from your university and get direct access to their data and build a proper app.